# Pypi: Not allowed to store or edit package information

Tags: python, package, setuptools, pypi

Pypi problems: Not allowed to store or edit package information. I'm following [this tutorial](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html%20%22this%20tutorial%22.).

.pypirc

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi
    pypitest

[pypi]
respository: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username: Redacted
password: Redacted

[pypitest]
respository: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username: Redacted
password: Redacted
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('README.rst') as f:
    readme = f.read()

setup(
    name = "quick",
    version = "0.1",
    packages = find_packages(),

    install_requires = ['numba>=0.17.0',
                        'numpy>=1.9.1',],

    url = 'https://github.com/David-OConnor/quick',
    description = "Fast implementation of numerical functions using Numba",
    long_description = readme,
    license = "apache",
    keywords = "fast, numba, numerical, optimized",

)
```

Command:

```
python setup.py register -r pypitest
```

Error:

```
Server response (403): You are not allowed to store 'quick' package information
```

I was able to successfully register using the form on pypi's test site, but when I upload using this:

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r pypitest
```

I get this, similiar, message:

```
error: HTTP Error 403: You are not allowed to edit 'quick' package information
```

I get the same error message when using Twine and Wheel, per [these instructions](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distributing.html#requirements-for-packaging-and-distributing). This problem comes up several times here and elsewhere, and has been resolved by registering before uploading, and verifying the PyPi account via email. I'm running into something else.

Comment: Somebody else has uploaded the package with same name before you?

Comment: This is not the case - evidence is that I'm able able to create the package using the website's form.

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track - I can create a repository on PyPi's test site, but not the main one. The error I receive, ie not being allowed to store package information, is different from if I use the name of an exisiting package, which is to the effect of the package already exists. It seems like 'quick' is a forbidden name, although I'm not sure why, and can't find a package by this name. I'm able to upload using a different name, but am still curious why I can't use 'quick'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From this list one can see all the packages on PyPi:

https://pypi.python.org/simple/

*quick* is there. The question author says he/she cannot create quick package, so he/she is not the package author on PyPi and somebody else has created a package with the same name before.